# How do order product categories - on a parent category page - in Woocommerce?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, order

I am using Woocommerce with Wordpress. Woocommerce allows you to create product categories. In addition You can set all those categories to have a specific parent category. That way you can go to the parent category page and display all the categories with an image and title.

I have done this. But the order of the categories is displayed in order by the date the category was added. How do I manually order these parent category pages OR order them alphabetically?

Currently we just have a page and have this short code which calls in the categories to be displayed from the specific parent

```
[product_categories number="-1" parent="4612" ]
```

Having trouble locating an answer. Maybe im wording the problem incorrectly?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's funny how we can set the order of products but not categories. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-terms-order/) should do it though.

Comment: Can I solve this problem with your plugin? Maybe I am just unclear on how it should be working.

Comment: Oh its working now for some reason. Must of been a cache issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. If you could mark this answer as correct I'd be grateful.